# The picture appears and disappears instantly

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

The picture appears and disappears instantly
I need to change the picture at the click of a button, but it appears and disappears instantly. What to do in this case, please help. By pressing I call the function php and in it the js code for changing the picture. Already everything I knew was retried. How to deal with this?
Game.php :

```
<?php
require "php/set_locations.php";
            

    
    
    
?>
<html>
<head><title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/GameStyle.css">
    
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="main_container">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="body_container">
           
        <div class="left_menu_container">
            <div class="left_menu_main_div">
                <a class="left_menu_button">
                <span class="left_menu_span"></span>
                </a>
                <nav class="left_menu_nav">
                    <a href="#" class="left_menu_link">Инвентарь</a>
                    <a href="#" class="left_menu_link">Персонаж</a>    
                    <a href="#" class="left_menu_link">Ремесло</a>    
                    <a href="#" class="left_menu_link">Охота</a>    
                </nav>
                <div class="left_menu_close_container"></div>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="js/Left_menu.js"></script>
            </div>
        </div>
                
            <div class="main_image_container">
                <div class="image_container">
                    <div class="img_container">
                        
                        <img class="image_location" id="image_location" name="image_location" src="">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="location_buttons_container">
                <div class="buttons_container">
                <form method="post">
                    <ul class="buttons_menu">
                        <li>Локации</li>
                        <li ><span ><button id="location_button_1" name="location_button_1">Главные ворота</button></span><em>3 сек.</em></li>
                        <li><span>Торговый квартал</span><em>2 сек</em></li>
                        <li><span>Замок</span><em>5 сек</em></li>
                        <li><span>Гильдия</span><em>4 сек</em></li>
                    </ul>
                        </form>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer_container">
            <div class="left_footer_block"></div>
            <div class="textarea_container">
            <textarea class="main_textArea" readonly></textarea>
                <div class="input_and_button_container">
                    <input class="input_for_main_textArea">
                    <div class="button_container">
                        <button class="set_text_button" ></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="onlinelist_container">
                <div class="online_list">
                    <ul class="online_list_ul">
                        <li><span>Герои в локации</span><em></em></li>
                        <li><span>IIITUKATUPKA</span><em>8</em></li>
                        <li><span>Tataliec</span><em>7</em></li>
                        <li><span>Nekita2012</span><em>6</em></li>
                        <li><span>Brion</span><em>5</em></li>
                        <li><span>Joken</span><em>4</em></li>
                        <li><span>Golden</span><em>5</em></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST["location_button_1"])){
        setLocation(4);
        } 
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

setLocation.php:

```
<?php

require "include_db.php";

function setLocation($url_image){
   $locationName = R::load('locationsdb', $url_image);
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    var img = "'.$locationName->location_image.'"; 
    var button1 = document.getElementById("location_button_1");
    button1.addEventListener("click", function(){
    });
    //document.getElementById("location_button_1").onclick = () => asd();
    </script>';
}
?>

<script>
function cccc(){
    
        document.getElementById("image_location").src =img;
}
</script>
```

Comment: May you only include the code which demonstrates the issue?

Comment: In the code, 1 active button and 1 function that is called. I included the code because I don’t know what exactly the problem is

Comment: I would recommend that you spend some time removing code until you’ve found where the issue lies.

Comment: Clicking `#location_button_1` submits the form, and the page will be refreshed. You've to add a different button, if you want to use JS to show the image. It would be simpler to put the correct src to the image at the server.

Comment: I didn’t point out right away, since then I will change the image constantly.
And what button should I put then? Not understood

Comment: How can this be implemented?

Comment: No, put the PHP code you currently have to the start of the page, set `$url` variable for src (default it to the empty string) instead of the script tag, and change the image tag like this: `<img class="image_location" src="<?=$url?>">`. You don't need any JS at all to change the image. Also, not exactly related, but never omit the DocTypeDeclaration.

Comment: It works, but the code works just like that, and it should by pressing a button. Do not know what could be the problem?

Comment: You're doing a double job in the original code. The script doesn't exist on the page before you once send a post request (submit the form). Then in the script you set the same submit button to listen clicks, and add the src, while you could add that src already in PHP. If you really need the script to set the src, use a different button (type of button), or pass the event object to the listener, and do `event.preventDefault();` in the listener function.

Comment: And what type of button can I put?

Comment: Please can you show by example how I can do this?